# MongoDB on an AWS instance, reason: errno:61 Connection refused

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

Mongo version 3.2

I set up MongoDB on an instance at AWS.

I then added it to the security group, as an exception for the firewall. Specifically, I set this up as a Customer TCP rule, with an exception for port 27017.

If I ssh to the instance and do:

```
  netstat -pl
```

I can see in the output:

tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         *:*                     LISTEN      2025/mongod

So mongodb is running, it is is listening on port 27017, and an exception for 27017 was added to the firewall.

But on my local Mac, when I try to connect, I get an error:

```
  mongo ec2-154-52-32-196.compute-1.amazonaws.com:27017/vvvvv -u ccccc -p xxxx

  MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6
  connecting to: ec2-54-152-232-96.compute-1.amazonaws.com:27017/vvvvv
  2016-05-06T09:52:07.281-0400 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 54.152.232.96:27017, reason: errno:61       Connection refused
  2016-05-06T09:52:07.281-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server       ec2-54-152-232-96.compute-1.amazonaws.com:27017, connection attempt failed :
  connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:231:14
  @(connect):1:6

  exception: connect failed
```

What else do I need to do to connect?

[[ UPDATE ]]

So I:

```
  emacs /etc/mongod.conf
```

and I add 0.0.0.0:

```
  net:
    port: 27017
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0
```

and then:

```
  service mongod restart
  mongod stop/waiting
  mongod start/running, process 5315
```

but I still get the same error as before

Hmmmm, I no longer see it in netstat -pl

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the netstat output:
`tcp 0 0 localhost:27017 : LISTEN 2025/mongod` - Looks like it is accepting connections only from localhost(samehost) - You have to make it run on 0.0.0.0 or the Public IP.

Comment: Ah, okay. Do you have a link to the documentation I should read?

Comment: You need to change the `bind_ip` to 0.0.0.0 in your /etc/mongodb.conf file.

Comment: I edited: # network interfaces                                                                                                                                                    
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0

Comment: I restarted but still the same problem

Comment: You should have this: `bind_ip=0.0.0.0` in your mongodb.conf and not `bindIp: 127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0`.
Once you are done changing, reload the mongodb service. 
Run `sudo netstat -lnp | grep mongo` and you should see `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost/127.0.0.1`, in the output.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for that!

Answer (score 8):

Check in /etc/mongod.conf

```
# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces.
bind_ip=127.0.0.1
```

Comment that line and reload the service. It should work.

Answer (score 6):

I modified in /etc/mongod.conf

```
# network interfaces
    net:
      port: 27017
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  
      bindIp: 0.0.0.0`
```

Then,

```
sudo service mongod restart


sudo netstat -utpl | grep mongo
```

And check if:     0.0.0.0:27017 appear,

Answer (score 0):

Writing this answer, in case the above mentioned answers don't solve the problem for someone, you should also add firewall exception in your linux(ubuntu in this case) by typing

```
> sudo ufw allow 27017/tcp
```

Hope that will help.